# Volume of a ellipsoidal shape

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I was given the following question:

[image]

My approach so far was to create a parabolic function:

y = 25/2 - (25^2)/392

Then I integrate from x = 0 to x = 14

Volume = 2 * pi * integral of y ^ 2

The answer I come to is 7330.38

The book's answer is 9162.98 cm^3

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since $y=\frac{25}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{14^2}}$ on the top half of the ellipse,

you can use $\displaystyle V=2\int_{0}^{14}\pi\frac{625}{4}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{14^2}\right)\;dx$ to get $\displaystyle V=\frac{625\pi}{2}\left[x-\frac{x^3}{3(14^2)}\right]_{0}^{14}=\frac{(625\pi)(14)}{3}=\frac{8750\pi}{3}$.